# How to setup a project to use TweetSharp

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, tweetsharp

I am trying to follow Pete Brown's introductory WPF tutorial which makes use of the TweetSharp libraries to interact with Twitter.

I have downloaded what appears to be the latest TweetSharp binaries (and a few others including the ReleaseCandidate) from Codeplex (http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/).

No matter what references I add and no matter what using statements I try, I cannot create a reference to the TwitterService for the FluentTwitter class.

I simply get the compiler error - "The type or namespace cannot be found".

Now I've noticed that the TweetSharp.dll that Pete references is 518KB but the one contained in each of my different downloads is only 84kb. (I've tried several times - I am getting the full download here).

The link from Pete's article to the TweetSharp libraries, no longer works (http://code.google.com/p/tweetsharp/).

What basic element am I missing here or what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: [Here](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/05/ngtweet-silverlight-client-for-tweeter.html) is an example of connecting to Twitter using TweetSharp in a Silverlight application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TweetSharp moved to CodePlex](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com) since that article was posted, which is why the link to Google Code is dead.

You need references to TweetSharp.dll, TweetSharp.Twitter.dll, (and for good measure Hammock.dll, and Newtonsoft.json.dll).

For using directives, if you're using the FluentTwitter approach:

```
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Fluent;
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Extensions;
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Model;
```

If you're using the TwitterService approach:

```
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Model;
using TweetSharp.Twitter.Service;
```

There are some other examples kicking around on CodePlex including some starter apps if you download the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I think now it's in github https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp CodePlex didn't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Tweetsharp library still on Codeplex? The link above has expired?

Or is Linq to Twitter a better option? I'm new to Twitter API and only need a few simple code examples (Search Feed, Geo Location & Post Photo to Twitter).